# multivariable calculus determing region and limits of integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, change-of-variable

Evaluate $$\iint_R\sqrt{|y-x^2|}dxdy~~~~~~\text{where}~ R=[-1,1]\times[0,2]$$
My effort: The above integral is 
$$=2\left(\int_0^1\int_{x^2}^2\sqrt{y-x^2}dydx+\int_0^1\int_0^{x^2}\sqrt{x^2-y}dydx\right)$$
$$=2\left(\{\pi/4~~+2/3\}+1/6\right)$$
The first inegral evaluated as follows
$$y=x^2sec^2\theta$$
Hence the integral becomes
$$=\int_0^1\left(\int_0^{sec^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{x^2}} \right)}x.\tan\theta. x^2.2\sec\theta.\sec\theta.\tan\theta d\theta \right)dx$$
$$=\dfrac{2}{3}\int_0^1x^3\tan^3\left(\sec^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{x^2}}\right)\right)dx$$
$$=\dfrac{2}{3}\int_0^1x^3\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{2-x^2}}{x}\right)^3dx $$
$$=\dfrac{2}{3}\int_0^1(2-x^2)^{3/2}dx$$
$$=\pi/4~~+2/3$$
 Is this the right approach?

Comment: Ahh, I see what you are doing. You are considering $y-x^2$ and $ -(y-x^2)$. On the second integral in the sum you should have $x \in [0,1]$. Also, why are you doubling the integral?

Comment: yup, it is a mistake

Comment: Okay. Well outside of that, it looks correct to me. You split up the integral into two pieces where the integrand is nonzero. I didn't catch this at first and that's why I wrote the other reply. That was clever. So yes, without the doubling, all should be well. I didn't check the computations, but the set-up would be correct.

Comment: we have to double the integral to accomodate for the left side of the x axis,isn't it?

Comment: Ahh, oh geez, I missed that too. You are correct. Good job on this one. Okay, everything looks fine now.

Comment: thanx for the check

Comment: Check your computation. Wolfram gives $$\frac{5}{3} + \frac{\pi}{2} \approx 3.237$$

Comment: i guess you didn't catch that either, my final answer is $2(\pi/4~~+2/3~~+1/6)$ check the third line of my question

Comment: Oh okay. Well I just checked the integrals separately on wolfram and they sum to the correct result. Everything here is correct. The only thing was the misprint on the original bounds for $x$, but you already knew that. Okay, cheers, and well done.

Comment: I updated my previous post. You can accept to close this question. I don't really know how to handle questions which are answered in comments, but for the sake of closing this one, I just quickly summed up the only mistake.

Comment: it's already chnaged